# mat-form-field as only child in component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular5

I have an error I cant understand.

I have a component quite simple myComponent.html:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value"
           class="uppercase"
           name="name"
           placeholder="{{ 'NAME' | translate }}"
           (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let element of elements" [value]="element.id">{{ element.name }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in parent.html:

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="header">
  <div fxFlex="50%" class="vehicle-selector">
     <my-component (change)="onSelectElement($event)"></my-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I have my code like this, mat-select is not shown properly:

[image: mat-select incorrect]

But if I remove  and include its code in parent.html it works fine.

How can I solve it?

Comment: can u provide this use case on stackblitz or plunker?

Comment: could you attach a snap of the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, btw you do not need the in your parent since you already have that in the child

```
<my-component ></my-component>
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-gd2jjv?file=app%2Fparent.html)**

Comment: can you try with my angular and material versions? Im using     "@angular/compiler": "5.2.4", and     "@angular/material": "5.2.0",

Comment: its there in the dependencies. it cannot be an issue with material

Comment: did you sort this issue

Comment: I finally solved, <my-component> added [_ngcontent-c12] wich added a padding-top

Comment: great ! then it must be a css issue

Comment: yes, I solve it with css class, just adding padding-top:0px to remove the 20 px I had. Thank you so much for your example, it was really useful for me

Comment: The link is broken, it would be great if you could fix it!